# Vector subspace equality proof/disproof.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $R,S,T$ are subspaces of vector space $V$, and $R+S=R+T$, does it follow $S=T$?

Please don't give a full proof, but some general help would be much appreciated. I get the basic idea that to show $S=T$ would be to show them to be subsets of one another. Not sure how to do this in a concrete way though.

Comment: Ah okay, Cheers guys :) Wasn't sure how to proceed, without being able to figure out if they were necessary equal or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You may have $S\neq T$ but $S,T\subseteq R$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Think about the following example. V is the plane, R is a line which passes the origin, S, T are different lines which also pass the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is wrong, $R+S=R+T$ does not imply $S=T$.

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $R=\mathbb{R}(1,0)$, then there exists an infinity of $S$ such that $R+S=V$.

Answer (score 0):

Another kind of example in infinite dimension:

Take $V=\mathbb R[X]$ and

- $R=\mathbb R[X]_{\leq 6}$
- $S=\mathbb R[X]_{\leq 3}$
- $T=\mathbb R[X]_{\leq 2}$.

Then $R+S=R+T$ but $S\ne T$.